# Show NSDecimalNumber as currency in IB

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, nsnumberformatter, nsdecimalnumber

I have a core data entity with a property amount, which is a  `NSDecimalNumber`.  For this property the entity's class has a method defined with an `NSDecimalNumber` as argument.

In Interface Builder I bound a table column to this property (using an `NSArrayController`) and on the column's cell I put an `NSNumberFormatter`.  The formatter is configured in IB as 'currency'.

Now, when I try to enter a number, I get the following error:

```
-[NSCFNumber decimalNumberBySubtracting:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001d5590
```

Apparently my setter method is receiving a regular `NSNumber` rather than an `NSDecimalNumber`.  Can I configure my formatter differently, perhaps in code rather than IB, or is the only option to add an additional setter with an `NSNumber` as argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me exactly where your issue is.  Either the formatter is giving you a straight NSNumber instead of a NSDecimalNumber or the core data is.

To make the NSNumberFormatter give you NSDecimalNumbers, use the method [-setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000202-BCIFGJGF)

To make the data store give you NSDecimalNumbers, make sure the relevant attribute in the model is set to "decimal number".

Answer (score 2):

Core Data doesn't store `NSDecimalNumber`, only `NSNumber`. `NSNumber` doesn't have the method that gets called.

You either need to change the entities definition to use `NSNumber` or build your own `NSValueTransformer` to store the `NSDecimalNumber` in Core Data.

Please look here for more details about properties: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002328-SW1

Comment: If the attribute type in the model is a decimal number, the generated object will be an NSDecimalNumber.

Comment: I just created a new project in which I created an entity with a decimal property. I then created an interface with a table and bound a column + formatter to this value.  The result: 1. the NSNumberFormatter which I bound to an outlet returns NO to generatesDecimalNumber; 2. If I ask for the class from the property's value, I get NSDecimalNumber, using this code:

NSLog(@"amount class = %@", [[obj amount] class]);